# Finding percentage of students within a score

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I would like resources to help me solve the following type of problem. Maybe a specific chapter to an open source book or something?

> given a set of test scores for a population, knowing that it is normally distributed with a mean $k$ and standard deviation $s$, how do I find the percentage of students scoring more than $p$ but no more than $q$ ($p$ is less than $q$)?

Comment: You'd have to know the distribution. Are the test scores normally distributed, for example?

Comment: Whoops, I left out that detail. I'll fix it

Comment: Anyway, this is a very standard probability question. An explanation can be found for ex. here : https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/normal-distribution-calculations.php